# Regular Expression - Unexpected Quantifier

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I am getting a javascript runtime (Unexpected Quantifier) error when a regular expression validator is fired.

The expression is - `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?${1,3}`

I am trying to validate a number with up to 3 decimal places.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

Comment: The extra `{1,3}` at the end shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra `{1,3}` from the end of your expression:

`^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,3})?$`

Comment: Thankyou, works when I remove that. Not sure how I didn't notice it!